# How to orgnize 301 redirects only for pages with get parmeters?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Here is a quick SEO question. We decided to split our web site into two different sites. Google has already crawled 50K pages which we want to move to another domain name. My question is what would be the best way to deal with it as we want only certain URLs to be redirected not the whole website.   Should I do mode rewire catch the get parameters and send them over to the new domain name? or should I do it with php headers?

---

olddomain.com becomes oldomain.com and newdomain.com

---

oldomain.com?name=jw&gsurname=black --> newdomain.com?name=jw&gsurname=black

---

oldomain.com with any other url structure should stay the same

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` directives together to match against query string values, like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=([^&]+)&gsurname=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com?name=%1&gsurname=%2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: sorry to bother. would you please add some explanation ot a link where i can read about  wildcard - want to understand the meaning of the symbols there.  How about testing is it trial and error, or there is a meaningful way to do it?

Comment: Those symbols are *regular expressions*. http://www.regular-expressions.info ... as for testing, I'm not sure what you mean. Test it. Does it work? Yes - good. No - bad.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean exactly that set of query parameters:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=([^&]+)&gsurname=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/$ http://newdomain.dom [R=301, L]
```

The RewriteCond looks at the query string and checks that the first parameter is name and the second parameter is gsurname. The `([^&]+)` collects all of the characters until it finds an ampersand (^& means not ampersand). The `(.*)$` collects characters until the end of the query string ($).

If the RewriteCond is true, then the RewriteRule redirects to the new domain. The query string is automatically passed along as-is.

Comment: thanks. sorry to bother. would you please add some explanation ot a link where i can read about  wildcard - want to understand the meaning of the symbols there.  How about testing is it trial and error, or there is a meaningful way to do it?

Comment: thank you. will have a look right now. so far it was very confusing as the testing was by trial and error

Comment: I added a bit of explanation to the answer.